# Octave max function

Tags: octave

There is something wrong with the max() function in Octave.

```
x=-3:0.1:3;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);
plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,max(y1,y2))
```

Just look at the images:
[image][image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the max function. The x resolution on the graph is set to 0.1, and so it samples at -2.3 and -2.4, and draws a line in-between. It does the same thing on sin/cos curves, but since there're not sharp corners, you can't tell. If you need a better graph, increase the resolution:

```
x=-3:0.01:3;
```